# How to create and save data using ORM within views.py in Django?

Tags: django, orm

I have a template that consists of a button. If a logged-in user clicks on it, it should generate a time and save it within the model and retrieve that time within the template. However, this does not get executed as expected. This is what I had done:

**models.py:**

```
class Mytime(models.Model):
    pid= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
```

**views.py:**

```
def generate_time(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        current_time = timezone.now()
        user_id = User.objects.get(username=request.GET.get('username')).pk
        if (Mytime.objects.filter(id__exact=user_id, time=current_time) in (None, '')): 
            time = Mytime.objects.create(time=current_time)
        else:
            pass
        data = Mytime.objects.values_list('time', flat=True)
    return HttpResponse(data) #return time to the template.
```

**interface.html:**

```
{% block content %}

    <div class="content-section">           
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" id ='get_time'> Click me </button>
            <h4 id='insert_time'></h4> //should display the time here from model
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

**JS AJAX code within the interface template:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#punchin').click(function () {
        username = localStorage.getItem('username');
        console.log(username)
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,  
            url: {% url 'generate_time' %},
            type: 'GET',
            data: {username: username},
            success: function(data) { 
                $("#insert_time").html(data.value);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, during execution, the time does not get generated. The AJAX call works but the if/else conditional doesn't get executed. How should I do this? Anything wrong within my views.py function?

Comment: Do you really need the check `request.is_ajax()`?

Comment: not really. I removed it but it still doesnt work.

Comment: Are you sure that `generate_time` is touched at all?

Comment: Yes, it is. I printed some statements and it worked. But the if conditional doesnt work.

Comment: what is the goal of generate_time method? You have some weird checks there and i could not comprehend its use.

Comment: Basically, I want to generate a time when a user clicks on a button. Once clicked, I want to check whether if the model (Mytime) has time data for a particular user. If not, it should generate a time for that user and save it to the model. After this, I want to return the generated time to the template. That is all. If there is a better way, please do tell me.

Comment: check my answer plz.

Comment: You're checking if a queryset is inside a list of literals which it wont be, what would you expect if the filter returned more than one result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use values_list as it returns a list of values. May be you should use the last entry from that user.
Also you should use queryset's exists() method.

Try this:

```
def generate_time(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if not Mytime.objects.filter(pid=request.user).exists():
            current_time = timezone.now()
            my_time = Mytime.objects.create(time=current_time, pid=user) 
            data = my_time.time

        else:
            data = Mytime.objects.filter(pid=request.user).last().time
        return HttpResponse(data) #return time to the template.
```

Comment: what does 'time.time' mean here? and what does user refer to (seen with 'pid=')?

Comment: to avoid misunderstanding i will rename it

Comment: your pid is a user object, so you can compare it with request's user

Comment: the data isnt getting retrieved back to the HTML page. the date is stored in my model though. How can I view it in my template? :)

Comment: replace   
<h4 id='insert_time'></h4>  with
<h4 id='insert_time'>{{insert_time}}</h4>

Answer (score 0):

When you write this:

```py
if (Mytime.objects.filter(id__exact=user_id, time=current_time) in (None, ''))
```

it is over complicated. I think that you just want to check if such an object exists, so you should simply go like this:

```py
if not Mytime.objects.filter(id__exact=user_id, time=current_time).exists():
    # do stuff
```

Also, I do not really understand what you are trying to do with `id` and so. You've got a `pid` user in your `Mytime` object, why not use it?

If you really want to keep your `time=current_time` thing in `filter()`, if condition will always be true (and I'm not sure that's what you want neither).